# Binding to Attached property of a DataContext property

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

I have an AttachedProperty like this:

```
Public Class AttachedProperties
    Public Shared ReadOnly IconProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Icon", GetType(ImageBrush), GetType(AttachedProperties), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Nothing, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender))

    Public Shared Sub SetIcon(ByVal element As Object, ByVal value As ImageBrush)
        element.SetValue(IconProperty, value)
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function GetIcon(ByVal element As Object) As ImageBrush
        Return CType(element.GetValue(IconProperty), ImageBrush)
    End Function
End Class
```

And a ViewModel like this:

```
Public Class ViewModel
    Public Property ShowingPage as Page

    Public Sub New()
        ShowingPage = New SamplePage()
    End Sub
End Class
```

While my `SamplePage` is something like this:

```
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="SamplePage">
    <local:AttachedProperties.Icon>
        <ImageBrush Source="Pack://..." /> <!-- Page's Icon -->
    </local:AttachedProperties.Icon>
</Page>
```

And finally I have a View which uses a `ViewModel` object as ViewModel:

```
<Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Class="MainWindow">

        <StackPanel>
            <!-- Showing Icon of page-->
            <Image Source="{Binding (AttachedProperties.Icon), Source=<<ShowingPage>>}" />

            <!-- Showing content of page -->
            <Frame Content="{Binding ShowingPage}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Window>
```

The question is **What should I write instead of the `<<ShowingPage>>` to show the page's icon?** Or if it's possible to bind to an attached property of a property on `DataContext`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attached Property has a owner that set or get based on owner, return unique value of that owner, So you have to bind to relative Page control and then refer to own Attached property:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=ShowingPage.(local:AttachedProperties.Icon)}" />
```

[Binding to AttchedProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451.aspx#singleattached)

Comment: Sorry but it's not a valid syntax! `ShowingPage.(AttachedProperties.Icon)` is not correct. it seems that it's a combination of binding to AttachedProperty and usual binding

Comment: @HamedZakeryMiab Are you test it? In same scenario this combination is worked perfectly.

Comment: @HamedZakeryMiab please report binding error in output window when debug mode.(like BindingExpression path error: '...' property not found on 'object'), I am sure this syntax have't problem except in Datacontext passing.

Comment: It does not compile at all! far away from Debug Errors. Did you have tested really?

Comment: @HamedZakeryMiab, Yes i tested with multiple scenario and it's worked, So what is compiler error? Don't forget XAML namespace (updated answer) local:AttachedProperties

Comment: The point was to add the namescpace just before the `AttachedProperties` mohandes :), thanks

Comment: @HamedZakeryMiab You will still be unable to bind the Image's Source property to an ImageBrush.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't bind the `Source` property of an Image control to a property of type `ImageBrush`. Either you use `ImageSource` as type of your attached property, or you bind (for example) the `Fill` property of a Rectangle to your ImageBrush.

The correct syntax for the binding would also have to include a namespace prefix:

```
<Rectangle Width="50" Height="50"
    Fill="{Binding Path=ShowingPage.(local:AttachedProperties.Icon)}" />
```